# Django Rest Framework - Unicode error

Tags: python, django, unicode, oauth, django-rest-framework

I am using django rest framework with django-oauth-toolkit, I have used it earlier and never have face this issue.

I have followed everything as per the documentation of [django-oauth-toolkit](https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.org/en/0.7.0/rest-framework/getting_started.html)

On trying to request for access token:

```
curl -H POST -d "grant_type=password&username=k@k.com&password=k&client_id=abc&client_secret=abc" http://127.0.0.1:8000/o/token/
```

I get the following stack trace:

```
[27/Nov/2014 06:11:41] ERROR [django.request:226] Internal Server Error: /o/token/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/K/Documents/PersonalData/rock_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 114, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/K/Documents/PersonalData/rock_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 69, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/K/Documents/PersonalData/rock_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 29, in _wrapper
    return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/K/Documents/PersonalData/rock_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 57, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/K/Documents/PersonalData/rock_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 25, in bound_func
    return func(self, *args2, **kwargs2)
  File "/Users/K/Documents/PersonalData/rock_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/braces/views/_forms.py", line 22, in dispatch
    return super(CsrfExemptMixin, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/K/Documents/PersonalData/rock_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 87, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/K/Documents/PersonalData/rock_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2_provider/views/base.py", line 154, in post
    url, headers, body, status = self.create_token_response(request)
  File "/Users/K/Documents/PersonalData/rock_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2_provider/views/mixins.py", line 124, in create_token_response
    return core.create_token_response(request)
  File "/Users/K/Documents/PersonalData/rock_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2_provider/oauth2_backends.py", line 106, in create_token_response
    headers)
  File "/Users/K/Documents/PersonalData/rock_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauthlib/oauth2/rfc6749/endpoints/base.py", line 61, in wrapper
    return f(endpoint, uri, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/K/Documents/PersonalData/rock_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauthlib/oauth2/rfc6749/endpoints/token.py", line 85, in create_token_response
    request = Request(uri, http_method=http_method, body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/Users/K/Documents/PersonalData/rock_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauthlib/common.py", line 398, in __init__
    self.headers = CaseInsensitiveDict(encode(headers or {}))
  File "/Users/K/Documents/PersonalData/rock_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauthlib/common.py", line 394, in <lambda>
    encode = lambda x: to_unicode(x, encoding) if encoding else x
  File "/Users/K/Documents/PersonalData/rock_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauthlib/common.py", line 342, in to_unicode
    return dict(((to_unicode(k, encoding), to_unicode(v, encoding)) for k, v in data))
  File "/Users/K/Documents/PersonalData/rock_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauthlib/common.py", line 342, in <genexpr>
    return dict(((to_unicode(k, encoding), to_unicode(v, encoding)) for k, v in data))
  File "/Users/K/Documents/PersonalData/rock_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauthlib/common.py", line 328, in to_unicode
    return unicode_type(data, encoding=encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xce in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

Also this same code is working on server but not on my local machine. I am on an ubuntu server. 
But my local machine is a Mac(Yosemite).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may escape your data as per http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html#POST

=> the '@' should be replaced by %40

See also http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: I Tried with all types of encoding. Doesnt work. I am feeling its some machine specific issue.